# Using Saiku-ui without saiku-server/mondrian?

Tags: saiku

Is it possible to use the saiku-ui component with a different jolap provider than mondrian, or with a different server backend than the saiku-server component?

I have been looking but I have not found an architecture description of how these pieces fit together and what interfaces they use to communicate.  Can anyone point me towards an understanding of what the saiku-ui wants to speak with and what the saiku-server is providing?

The reason for my interest is that I have a set of data spread across hundreds of csv files that I would like to query with a pivot and charting tool.  It looks like the standard way to use this with saiku would be to have an ETL process to load in to an RDBMS.  However, this would not be a simple process because the files and content and the way the files relate to each other vary, so the ETL would have to do a lot of inspection of the data sources to figure it out.

Given this it seems to me that I would have three options in how to use saiku:

1) write a complex ETL to load in to a rdbms, and then use a standard jdbc driver to provide the data to modrian.  A side function of the ETL would be to analyze the inputs and write the mondrian schema file describing the cubes.

2) write a jdbc driver to access the data natively.  This driver would parse sql and provide access to the underlying tables.  Essentially this would be a custom r/o dbms written on top of the csv files.  The jdbc connection would be used by mondrian to access the data.  A side function of this custom dbms would be to produce the mondrian schema file.

3) write a tool that provides a jolap interface to the native data (accepts discovery and mdx queries).  This would bypass mondrian entirely and interface with the ui.

I may be a bit naive here but I consider each of the three options to be feasible.  Option #1 is my least preferred because of the likelihood of the data in the rdbms becoming out of sync with the cvs files.  Option #3 is most preferred because the data are simple, so not much aggregating required and I suspect that mdx will be easier to parse than sql.

So, if i could produce my own jolap data source would it be possible to hook the saiku-ui tools up to it?  Where would I look to find out the interface configuration details?

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago, @ronaldbouman created xmondrian - the set of tools with the olap server, and web ui tools for xmla browsing and visualusation. But that project was not updating, and has no source code.

I just updated olap server and libraries to the latest versions.
You may get it here and build:. 
https://github.com/Muritiku/xmondrian-build.

You may use web package as the example. The mondrian server works with the saiku-ui.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO,

I would not be as confident as your are, because it took Julian Hyde more than a decade to build Mondrian (MDX->SQL) and Calcite (SQL), fulfilling your last two proposals.

You might simply consider using Calcite, or even better Dremio. Dremio has a JDBC interface, and can query directories of CSV files in SQL. I tested Saiku over Dremio successfully (with a schema based on two separate RDBMS). Just be careful to setup tables' schema accordingly in the Mondrian v4 schema.

Best regards,
Fabrice Etanchaud

[Dremio](http://www.dremio.com)